# Fragment Android

Tags: android-fragment

Estou tentando fazer um app com o layout Navigation Drawer, porem usa Fragments, não estou conseguindo chamar outra tela utilizando Fragments.

```
             Login fragment = new Login();
             android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =                              getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Codigo que eu utlizava , porem não da mais, da erro no fragment_container. Alguem poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Veja assim:

```
        Login fragment = new Login();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

Aqui estou usando `getActivity()` porque estou chamando o fragmento login de dentro de outro fragmento. Talvez você tenha de adaptar à sua logica.